# Фильтрация групп

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем доброго времени суток, подскажите с задачей. Несколько суток бьюсь, но до конца не пойму как решить.
Условие задачи:
Выведите типы комнат (поле home_type) и разницу между самым дорогим и самым дешевым представителем данного типа. В итоговую выборку включите только те типы жилья, количество которых в таблице Rooms больше или равно 2.
Для вывода разницы стоимости используйте псевдоним difference.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы точно пытаетесь решить эту задачу несколько суток? А то выглядит так, будто вы написали этот запрос за секунду, даже не прочитав условие. В вашем запросе нету даже нахождения разницы между `MAX` и `MIN`.

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Чтобы найти разность между самым дорогим и дешёвым жильём данного типа, достаточно взять разность для результатов соответствуюющих агрегирующих функций.
Для проверки количества следует применить условие `HAVING COUNT(*)` после группировки.

```sql
SELECT home_type, MAX(price) - MIN(price) AS difference -- вывод разницы
FROM Rooms
GROUP BY home_type
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  -- проверка, что количество данного типа жилья от 2 и выше
```

[онлайн демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/870995/1)

Comment: Ух ты, аж два анонимных минуса

Comment: Благодарю с разъяснения)